# Looping through each column of excel and dragging formula down by one cell each

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm new to VBA and would like to know how to do some stuff with it. As seen in the table below, what I would normally do is drag the formula down one cell for each column as my data expands over time. Is there a quick and efficient way for me to loop through each column doing that drag down action automatically?

[image: Example]

Comment: Any code so far? You need a loop through the columns, then autofill to the endrow

Comment: What formula are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Currently I have just drawn a named range over this table and I'm not sure with the syntax etc on looping column by column. Sorry this picture is a bit misleading as there are a few more columns at the front. I have several of these named ranges in a worksheet and I'm not sure if it's efficient to loop through all 4 named ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Code assumes that the formula is in cell 2 of the column

```
Option Explicit

Sub autofill()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim y

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

'range
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:" & ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address)

'looping
For Each y In rng

'autofilling, note the split function retreiving the letter for the range
   ws.Range(Split(Cells(, y).Address, "$")(1) & "2").autofill Destination:=ws.Range(Split(Cells(, y).Address, "$")(1) & "2:" & Split(Cells(, y).Address, "$")(1) & ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
Next y

End Sub
```